# Spring Cloud Contract dockerized stub runner - Trigger message from non-jvm application

Tags: spring, message-queue, spring-cloud-contract

I'm currently investigating possibility of using Spring Cloud Contract for testing my company microservices. Iv found information about some capabilities of Spring Cloud Contract to be used with non-jvm services (https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/13/spring-cloud-contract-in-a-polyglot-world).

Our software will communicate over messages queue. I need to find out how can i trigger sending message from containerized stub runner, without using any of jvm specific integrations (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#features-messaging). Does anybody know if this is even supported?